# Bottom Navigation bar not show the content

Tags: java, android, xml

I used Bottom Navigation Activity which is in the android studio.
In the MainActivity I made a list view (user can change it to grid view) which is supposed to be in home item. When I run the project, there is no content in home item

**In MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private ViewStub stubGrid;
    private ViewStub stubList;
    private ListView listView;
    private GridView gridView;
    public ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    public GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;
    public List<Product> productList;
    private int currentViewMode = 0;

    static final int VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW = 1;
    static final int VIEW_MODE_GRIDVIEW = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        stubList = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_list);
        stubGrid = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_grid);


        //Inflate ViewStub before get view

        stubList.inflate();
        stubGrid.inflate();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGridView);

        //get list of product
        getProductList();


        //Get current view mode in share reference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ViewMode",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentViewMode = sharedPreferences.getInt("currentViewMode",
                VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW);//Default is view listview
        //Register item lick
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick);
        switchView();



        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }


    private void switchView() {

        if(VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW == currentViewMode) {
            //Display listview
            stubList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Hide gridview
            stubGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            //Hide listview
            stubList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Display gridview
            stubGrid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        setAdapters();
    }


    private void setAdapters() {
        if(VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW == currentViewMode) {
            listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,
                    productList);
            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        } else {
            gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item,
                    productList);
            gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
        }
    }

    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        //pseudo code to get product, replace your code to get real product here
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.ii1, " Story name","http://www.storiesrealistic.com","","1"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i2, "اStory name","http://www.cairodar.com/542427/","","2"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i3, "Story name","http://www.kids.jo/","","3"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i4, "Story name","http://mawdoo3.com/","","4"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i5, "Story name","http://mawdoo3.com/","","5"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i13, "Story name","http://mawdoo3.com/","","6"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i8, "Story name","http://kids.almo7eb.com/","","7"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i9, "Story name","http://www.storiesrealistic.com/","","8"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i7, "Story name","http://www.storiesrealistic.com/","","9"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i10, "Story name","https://www.roro44.net/90107/","","10"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i11, "Story name","http://www.storiesrealistic.com/","","11"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i12, "Story name","http://mawdoo3.com/","","12"));
        productList.add(new Product(R.drawable.i6, "Story name","http://www.storiesrealistic.com/","","13" ));

        return productList;
    }

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClick = new
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                        long id) {
                    //Do any thing when user click to item
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            productList.get(position).getTitle(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    Bundle b= new Bundle();
                    b.putString("Story Name", productList.get(position).getTitle());
                    b.putInt("Story Image",productList.get(position).getImageId());
                    b.putString("Story Title",productList.get(position).getTitle());
                    b.putString("Source", productList.get(position).getSource());
                    b.putString("Genres", productList.get(position).getGenres());
                    b.putString("Reader", productList.get(position).getRead());
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);


                }
            };


    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_fav:

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_share:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String shareBody="Your Body Here";
                    String shareSub="Your Subject Here";
                    myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSub);
                    myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent,"Share using"));

                    return false;
                case R.id.nav_Rating:

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_send:
                    Intent chooser= null;
                    myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("Mail To:"));
                    myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"norry-7@hotmail.com"});
                    myIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    chooser= Intent.createChooser(myIntent,"Send Email");
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };
}
```

Share and Send items work correctly, but at home item nothing show. I but the list view code in MainActivity where

```
setContentView
```

at `activity_main`

Comment: You are doing nothing on *navigation_home* and *navigation_fav*. or return *false*

Comment: for navigaion_fav yes I know i didn't started but for home what should I write ? I think since the app start in activity_main, it is supposed to show the activity_main which is the home item

Comment: I tried before in Navigation drawer it worked withe me

Comment: is home item a fragment?

Comment: no I did not use any fragment and I didn't want to use fragment

Comment: Can you please post your complete Activity code?

Comment: I edit my question. I post the complete MainActivity

Comment: I solve it. The problem was in layout. It must to use ConstraintLayout instead of LinerLayout

Comment: Thanks a lot and I am sorry if I wasted your time